# First time SONAR setup with Maven, getting a error on RulePriority, analysis fails

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to setup SONAR on a server. I have Maven 3.0.3 and using Sonar 3.1.1 with a Java project.

Part way through the `mvn sonar:sonar`, I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXX-common: Can not execute Sonar: No enum const class org.sonar.api.rules.RulePriority.3 -> [Help 1]
```

I have setup Sonar before and never saw this, it has always been unzip and go.  But on this particular server I keep getting this error.

I tried creating a blank rule set, but the error still pops up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Fixed the issue. The upgrade from 3.0 to 3.1.1 must have gone bad or I failed to do something. I trashed the whole install and the problem when away (when I started with a clean sonar 3.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the same problem described here 
http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/Xpath-rules-gt-Failed-startup-of-context-td3183230.html

You might find it useful